# How to create a patch with Git Extensions

Tags: git, patch, git-extensions

Is there a way to create a patch from selected commits in the user interface from Git Extensions?

I know how to export a patch trough command line, but I wonder if there is a similar functionality like in the TortoiseHg user interface (right click → *Export* -> ...)

So far I have only found the functionality to apply a patch in the user interface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Commands -> Format patch. In the window that pops up, you can select multiple commits.

The result will be one patch file per commit. That's in line with the default behavior of `git format-patch`.

The UI unfortunatelly provides no way to put them all in one file. You could just use a simple script of some sort to put the contents of all the created patch files into one file.

Comment: Is there any way we can export the actual files (added or updated) in specific commit. let say I change 10 files in multiple folder and when i do some kind of export, it create all the folder structure and 10 files in them, so that I have only files those were changed or update and I just replace them where ever I want (to speed up FTP) ?

Answer (score 6):

Adding image, [referenced git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org](http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patches.html)
[image]